# Failed to build llvm-clang by FileCheck.exe in Windows7 and MinGW and MSYS

Tags: windows, mingw, llvm-clang, msys

I failed to build llvm-clang by FileCheck.exe in Windows7(64bit) and MinGW and MSYS.
Reference document for build is
https://web.archive.org/web/20140301212210/http://www.bencode.net/blog/2012/10/20/clangonwindows/
Failed at 'make' of 'Step 5'.
Why?

errors:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/my-name/tmp/build/lib/Support'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/my-name/tmp/build/lib/Support'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/my-name/tmp/build/lib/TableGen'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/my-name/tmp/build/lib/TableGen'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/my-name/tmp/build/utils'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/my-name/tmp/build/utils/FileCheck'
llvm[2]: Linking Release+Asserts executable FileCheck (without symbols)
C:/mingw64/msys/home/my-name/tmp/build/Release+Asserts/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Path.o):Path.cpp:(.text+0x466c): undefined reference to `FOLDERID_LocalAppData'
C:/mingw64/msys/home/my-name/tmp/build/Release+Asserts/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Path.o):Path.cpp:(.text+0x4674): undefined reference to `FOLDERID_LocalAppData'
C:/mingw64/msys/home/my-name/tmp/build/Release+Asserts/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Path.o):Path.cpp:(.text+0x467d): undefined reference to `FOLDERID_LocalAppData'
C:/mingw64/msys/home/my-name/tmp/build/Release+Asserts/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Path.o):Path.cpp:(.text+0x4686): undefined reference to `FOLDERID_LocalAppData'
C:/mingw64/msys/home/my-name/tmp/build/Release+Asserts/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Path.o):Path.cpp:(.text+0x46ac): undefined reference to `FOLDERID_Profile'
C:/mingw64/msys/home/my-name/tmp/build/Release+Asserts/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Path.o):Path.cpp:(.text+0x46b4): undefined reference to `FOLDERID_Profile'
C:/mingw64/msys/home/my-name/tmp/build/Release+Asserts/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Path.o):Path.cpp:(.text+0x46bd): undefined reference to `FOLDERID_Profile'
C:/mingw64/msys/home/my-name/tmp/build/Release+Asserts/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Path.o):Path.cpp:(.text+0x46c6): undefined reference to `FOLDERID_Profile'
C:/mingw64/msys/home/my-name/tmp/build/Release+Asserts/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Path.o):Path.cpp:(.text+0x6bf5): undefined reference to `FOLDERID_LocalAppData'
C:/mingw64/msys/home/my-name/tmp/build/Release+Asserts/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Path.o):Path.cpp:(.text+0x6c01): undefined reference to `FOLDERID_LocalAppData'
C:/mingw64/msys/home/my-name/tmp/build/Release+Asserts/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Path.o):Path.cpp:(.text+0x6c0e): undefined reference to `FOLDERID_LocalAppData'
C:/mingw64/msys/home/my-name/tmp/build/Release+Asserts/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Path.o):Path.cpp:(.text+0x6c17): undefined reference to `FOLDERID_LocalAppData'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/home/my-name/tmp/llvm/Makefile.rules:1434: recipe for target `/usr/home/my-name/tmp/build/Release+Asserts/bin/FileCheck.exe' failed
make[2]: *** [/usr/home/my-name/tmp/build/Release+Asserts/bin/FileCheck.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/my-name/tmp/build/utils/FileCheck'
/usr/home/my-name/tmp/llvm/Makefile.rules:939: recipe for target `FileCheck/.makeall' failed
make[1]: *** [FileCheck/.makeall] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/my-name/tmp/build/utils'
/usr/home/my-name/tmp/llvm/Makefile.rules:880: recipe for target `all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```